# Listar pastas e subpastas cmd

Tags: cmd

Eu gostaria de exibir o nome do diretório seguido das pastas que estão dentro dele na ordem.

Testei o comando:

```
dir /s /b /o:g /ad
```

E a saída foi gerada assim:

```
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Animes
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Series
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Nova pasta
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Series\Teen Wolf
```

Mas eu gostaria que fosse gerada assim:

```
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Animes
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Series
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Series\Teen Wolf
C:\Users\JG\Pictures\Nova pasta
```

Alguém sabe algum comando ou atributo que faça isso?

Comment: O comando tree atende?

Comment: Com o comando tree consigo uma saída assim? Porque preciso gravar essa saída em um arquivo para depois jogar no Excel.

Comment: Você pode fazer tree > exemplo.txt

Comment: Deu certo com tree, mas não consegui uma saída assim bonitinha. O txt fica com uns caracteres a mais... Mas já é alguma coisa. Obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Atualizado - ao usar o sort colocou como o desejado :

```
dir /a:d /s /b | sort
```

Comment: Eu tentei ordernar por nome ("o:n"), mas também não deu certo. A saída foi a mesma. T ^ T

Comment: Yaaaaaaay ~ Deu certo!!!! Nossa!!! Muito Obrigada, Claudio ^ w^

Comment: Olá @MiuinWonderland, uma dica. Quando você tiver uma resposta que satisfaça sua pergunta selecione-a como melhor resposta na marca verde.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar o comando sem o dois pontos(":"), veja:

```
dir /s /b /OG /AD
```

Answer (score 0):

> Seria esse **comando** que você procuras para gerar a **listagem com caminho completo ordenado por nome?**

<kbd>**`ordenar por nome adicione: /on (dir /s /b /o:g /ad /on)`**</kbd>

<kbd>**`for /f "tokens=*delims= " %i in ('dir /s /b /o:g /ad /on')do @echo/%~fi`**</kbd>

> Na **linha de comando**:

```bat
dir /s /b /o:g /ad /on
rem :: num looping for :: 
for /f "tokens=*delims= " %i in ('dir /s /b /o:g /ad /on')do @echo/"%~fi
```

> No **arquivo bat**:

```bat
@echo off & dir /s /b /o:g /ad /on
rem :: num looping for :: 
@echo off & for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('dir /s /b /o:g /ad /on')do echo/%%~fi
```

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]